# CDI cross BDA bean injection in Wildfly 8.1

Tags: cdi, wildfly, weld, wildfly-8, weld2

I have an EAR file with the following structure:

- lib

  - jar.jar

    - Test1
    - Test2
- ejb.jar

  - Test1Impl
- war.war

  - Test2Impl
  - TestServlet

The jar.jar contains two interfaces

- Test1
- Test2

The TestServlet injects Test1 which resolves to Test1Impl only if I have a manifest Class-Path entry in war.war to ejb.jar.
Test1Impl injects Test2 which resolves to Test2Impl only if I have a manifest Class-Path entry in ejb.jar to war.war.

The tip entry **Matching the classloader structure for the deployment** of the [Weld documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/ri-spi.html#d0e5351) explains why I need the manifest entries.
How is this cross BDA injection supposed to work normally? Adding Class-Path manifest entries seems a bit stupid because actually I don't want the implementations to be visible. I only want that the beans from other subdeployments to be visible. Is there any way to do that?

Here the implementations

```
public class Test1Impl implements Test1 {

    @Inject
    private Test2 test2;

    public void hello() {
        System.out.println(test2.getString());
    }

}

public class Test2Impl implements Test2 {

    public String getString() {
        return "Hello";
    }

}

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/test")
public class TestServlet implements Servlet {

    @Inject
    private Test1 test;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }

    public ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
        return null;
    }

    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        test.hello();
    }

    public String getServletInfo() {
        return null;
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

And here the application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd"
             version="7">
  <description>The EAR</description>
  <display-name>ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <ejb>ejb.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>war.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

Comment: Do you have any scopes defined for `Test1Impl` or `Test2Impl`? What does your `beans.xml` look like?

Comment: In my real application ```Test1Impl``` would be a stateless EJB and ```Test2Impl``` a request scoped CDI bean. The ```beans.xml``` is empty.

Comment: Can you update your question to specify how your `application.xml` looks?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [CDI reference](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/CDI+Reference) in the section **Using CDI Beans from outside the deployment** a jboss-deployment-structure.xml with the appropriate dependencies is required.
Although doing this fixed my problems, I think that the CDI spec should define a portable way for doing this for enterprise applications.

Comment: That section only has to do with archives not contained within the same deployment.  For all intents and purposes, you should consider an EAR as one deployment.

Comment: Although you are right about the *not contained* part, the follow-up section **JBoss Deployment Structure File** of the page **Class Loading in WildFly** uses a meta-inf import for an ejb module contained in the EAR. It would be great if I didn't need to configure this because as you wrote, the EAR should be considered as one deployment, but unfortunately that doesn't work as expected.